# Highlight row is not getting disappear after I click the next table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js, ember-1

I need to create background as yellow while selecting the gear icon for the menu option in the table row, I have tried the below code for highlighting the table row,

```
var view = Core.view.Menu.create({
    model: model,
    menuContext: { ibmm: ibmm },
    anchor: this.$(),
    highlight: this.$().parents('tr:first').css('background-color','yellow')
});
view.show();
```

While selecting the menu from the table row (hidden) with the gear icon, the background color is coming well.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

corresponding html file is below

```
<tr id="ember23242" class="ember-view content-row body-row-view container-view" tabindex="0" aria-label="">
```

But when I move to the next table row(non hidden), the past table row color is still in yellow color, not getting disappear.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I'm using the below css code for creating the highlight when i'm clicking the row

```
table.content-table.highlighted tr.content-row:focus {
  background: #FFFF99 none 0 0 repeat;
}
```

Can anybody suggest me code for this. I’m using Ember 1.4.0.

Comment: can you show how you are going on next table row?

Comment: Please wait @BhushanKawadkar, I'll edit in my question

Comment: when you select another table row, is there any row event get triggered? can you share relevant html code?

Comment: No @BhushanKawadkar, there is no row event get triggered. Wait I'll add the html and css code

Comment: Hi @BhushanKawadkar, I have edited. 'ember-view content-row body-row-view container-view' this is common for all the table row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below jquery to reset your background color where event will occur on focusout.

```
$(function(){
  $("table.content-table.highlighted tr.content-row").on("focusout", function(){
        $(this).css('background','#FFFF00 none 0 0 repeat'); // change color code as per your need
  });
});
```

Comment: When I add this code also the existing table row is not getting disappear. Can you please check once again

Comment: Is that I need to remove this .css('background-color','yellow')

Comment: This is not working. Can you please suggest me some other code

Comment: can you please recreate your issue on code snipped or jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference between [`:first`](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first) and [`:first-child`](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
var view = Core.view.Menu.create({
    model: model,
    menuContext: { ibmm: ibmm },
    anchor: this.$(),
    highlight: this.$().parents('tr:first-child').css('background-color','yellow')
});
view.show();
```

Comment: Hi @Arthur. When I tried your code, the background color even not showing when I click for an menu. Please see the updated question of mine